Sleepwatcher not executing script when user resumes keyboard or mouse activity
My goal is to run a script when my external monitor is turned back on (by moving mouse or keyboard press). Script runs fine when executed from terminal. I have a screen saver that starts running at 5 min of inactivity. External monitor turns of at 10 minutes. See screenshot. 
Using this code doesn't work:
/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --wakeup /Users/someusername/.wakeup 

Because this is not a true sleep state. When I go to Apple > Sleep in the menubar that is a true sleep state.
Next thing I tried was this:
/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --resume /Users/someusername/.wakeup -b 300 

Should execute the script when the user resumes keyboard or mouse activity after a break with a duration given with the -b option. For testing purposes I have set the break to 30 seconds. I can see sleepwatcher running in Activity Monitor but the script doesn't run. Any tips on how to fix this?
